# AJAX Drag & Drop Server Reordering

Tags: php, datatables

I'm using the [jQuery DataTables Row Reordering plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/) to reorder a list of quizzes on a page. What is the best way to handle the [AJAX response](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/ServerSideIntegration) and persist the changes to the database (MySQL in my case)?

Currently, I just pull the list of quizzes from the database, pass them to a function that does the reordering, and then loop through the result to save the quizzes back to the database. Here's my reordering function with an example test case and output:

```
<?php
 /**
 * Reorders a list of quizzes.
 * Assumes that the input list of quizzes is in sorted
 * order and looks like this:
 *
 *  $quizzes = array(array('id'=>27, 'sort_order'=>1), ...);quiz_id:{$quiz['id']} from: $from to: $to dir: $dir\n";
        if($counter === $to) {
            $next = $quiz;
        } else if(count($quizzes) === $from) {
            array_pop($quizzes); // discard
            continue;
        } else {
            $next = array_pop($quizzes);
        }

        $next['sort_changed'] = ($next['sort_order'] !== $counter);
        $next['sort_diff'] = $counter - $next['sort_order'];
        $next['sort_order'] = $counter;

        $reordered[] = $next;
        $counter--;
    }

    return array_reverse($reordered);
}
?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
$quizzes = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'sort_order' => 1),
    array('id' => 2, 'sort_order' => 2),
    array('id' => 3, 'sort_order' => 3),
    array('id' => 4, 'sort_order' => 4),
    array('id' => 5, 'sort_order' => 5)
);
$from = 4;
$quiz = $quizzes[$from-1];
$to = 1;

$result = reorder($quizzes, count($quizzes), $quiz, $from, $to, 'back');
print json_encode($result);
?>
```

With output like this:

```
[{"id":4,"sort_order":1,"sort_changed":true,"sort_diff":-3},
{"id":1,"sort_order":2,"sort_changed":true,"sort_diff":1},
{"id":2,"sort_order":3,"sort_changed":true,"sort_diff":1},
{"id":3,"sort_order":4,"sort_changed":true,"sort_diff":1},
{"id":5,"sort_order":5,"sort_changed":false,"sort_diff":0}]
```

Am I over-thinking this? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Just using jQuery UI for drag and drop.  It's so much easier :)  You can literally be like, "`onDrop: .ajax(..)`"

Comment: You're definitely overthinking it!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought =)